# SMOTE in r reducing sample size significantly

Tags: r, statistics, sample-size

I have a data set with around 130000 records. The records divided in two class of target variable,0 & 1. 1 contains only 0.09% of total proportion.

I'm running my analysis in R-3.5.1 on Windows 10. I used SMOTE algorithm to work with this imbalanced data set.

I used following code to handle imbalanced data set

```
library(DMwR)
data_code$target=as.factor(data_code$target) #Converted to factor as 
# SMOTE works with factor data type
smoted_data <- SMOTE(target~., data_code, perc.over=100)
```

But after executing the code,I'm seeing the count for 0 is 212 & 1 is also 212 which is significant reduction of my sample size.Can you suggest me how do I handle this imbalanced data set with SMOTE without changing my data size

Comment: Please give an example Code reproducing your problem, so people can try and propose a solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi @denis, I already have given the code what I'm using in my post. What else you want?

Comment: What people want, as described extensively in the link I gave, is example data. If I copy paste your code, I will not get anything because I don't know `data_code`. If I propose a solution, I can't test it. I would have to create an example myself, but it is supposed to be your part of the job here. Creat a fake `data_code` set that reproduce the problem and post it in your question (avoid external link).

Comment: Sorry, I can't able to share with you the data_code as it contains client data.

Comment: Again, I/we don't ask you to share the data set: create a fake data set that reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to play a bit with the two parameters avaiable from the function: `perc.over` and `perc.under`.

As per the [doc](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DMwR/versions/0.4.1/topics/SMOTE) from `SMOTE`:

> The parameters perc.over and perc.under control the amount of
>   over-sampling of the minority class and under-sampling of the majority
>   classes, respectively.

So:

> perc.over will tipically be a number above 100. With this type of
>   values, for each case in the orginal data set belonging to the
>   minority class, perc.over/100 new examples of that class will be
>   created

I can't see your data but, if your minority class has 100 cases and `perc.over=100`, the algorithm will generate 100/100 = 1 new cases from that class.

> The parameter perc.under controls the proportion of cases of the
>   majority class that will be randomly selected for the final "balanced"
>   data set. This proportion is calculated with respect to the number of
>   newly generated minority class cases.

So for example a value of `perc.under=100` will select from the majority class on the original data the same amount of observation that have been generated for the minority class.

In our example just 1 new case was generated so it will add just another one, resulting in a new dataset with 2 cases.

I suggest to use values above 100 for `perc.over`, and an even higher value for `perc.under` (defaults are 100 and 200).

Keep in mind that you're adding new observations that are **not real** in your minority class, I'd try to keep these under control.

Numeric example:

```
set.seed(123)

data <- data.frame(var1 = sample(50),
                   var2 = sample(50),
                   out = as.factor(rbinom(50, 1, prob=0.1)))

table(data$out)
#  0  1 
# 43  7 # 50 rows total (original data)
smote_data <- DMwR::SMOTE(out ~ var1, data, perc.over = 200, perc.under = 400)
table(smote_data$out)
#  0  1 
# 56 21 # 77 rows total (smote data)
```

Comment: very  nice explanation. Thanks a lot

Comment: Before I have 5822 rows and after running this line I am getting only 2436 rows. Can you tell me what's wrong in this???

`data_oversampled <- DMwR::SMOTE(targetVar ~ ., trainingData, prec.over = 200,prec.under = 400)`

I only want to increase the minority and keep the majority

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the `DMwR` package is the `smotefamily` package which does *not* reduce the sample size.

Instead, it creates additional data (= synthesized data) from the minority class, and adds it to the original data. So the output in the `$data` argument is ready for training. To tune the amount of synthesized data, you can modify the parameter `dup_size`. However, the default `dup_size = 0` already optimizes the output to achieve balanced classes, so you don't need to tune it.

This is greatly explained in this [blog post](http://rikunert.com/SMOTE_explained) by Richard Richard.

Example code (with features in first two columns):

```
smote1 <- smotefamily::SMOTE(features, target, K = 4, dup_size = 0)
formula1 <- "class ~ ." %>% as.formula
model.smote <- caret::train(formula1, method = "rpart", smote1$data)
predictions.smote <- predict(model.smote, smote1$data[,1:2]) %>% print
cv2 <- confusionMatrix(smote1$data$class %>% as.factor, predictions.smote)
```

I find the `smotefamily::SMOTE` more convenient because you don't have to tune the two parameters `perc_over` and `perc_under` until you get an acceptable sample size, and the `DMwR::SMOTE` often generates NA values.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little too late to answer your question but hope this answer would help others! The package you're using is `DMwR` which uses a  [combination of SMOTE and under-sampling of the majority class](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.1813.pdf).

I'd suggest you to use `smotefamily::SMOTE` as it only over samples the minority class, so you wouldn't lose your majority class observations.